# Error Inflating class fragment -Error in xml

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am getting Error inflating class fragment in the xml file as well.

Can find the error .Have tried all the possible solutions
Please help guys

Please Find the Code Below

**Error Log**

```
03-03 15:23:34.775: E/AndroidRuntime(1672): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-03 15:23:34.775: E/AndroidRuntime(1672): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ib.qezyplay/com.ib.qezyplay.UserMainScreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #74: Error inflating class fragment
03-03 15:23:34.775: E/AndroidRuntime(1672):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
03-03 15:23:34.775: E/AndroidRuntime(1672):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2122)
03-03 15:23:34.775: E/AndroidRuntime(1672):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
03-03 15:23:34.775: E/AndroidRuntime(1672):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1228)
03-03 15:23:34.775: E/AndroidRuntime(1672):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-03 15:23:34.775: E/AndroidRuntime(1672):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-03 15:23:34.775: E/AndroidRuntime(1672):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
03-03 15:23:34.775: E/AndroidRuntime(1672):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-03 15:23:34.775: E/AndroidRuntime(1672):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-03 15:23:34.775: E/AndroidRuntime(1672):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
03-03 15:23:34.775: E/AndroidRuntime(1672):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
03-03 15:23:34.775: E/AndroidRuntime(1672):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-03 15:23:34.775: E/AndroidRuntime(1672): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #74: Error inflating class fragment
03-03 15:23:34.775: E/AndroidRuntime(1672):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
03-03 15:23:34.775: E/AndroidRuntime(1672):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
03-03 15:23:34.775: E/AndroidRuntime(1672):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
03-03 15:23:34.775: E/AndroidRuntime(1672):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
03-03 15:23:34.775: E/AndroidRuntime(1672):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
03-03 15:23:34.775: E/AndroidRuntime(1672):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
03-03 15:23:34.775: E/AndroidRuntime(1672):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
03-03 15:23:34.775: E/AndroidRuntime(1672):     at com.ib.qezyplay.UserMainScreen.onCreate(UserMainScreen.java:220)
03-03 15:23:34.775: E/AndroidRuntime(1672):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5163)
03-03 15:23:34.775: E/AndroidRuntime(1672):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
03-03 15:23:34.775: E/AndroidRuntime(1672):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2061)
03-03 15:23:34.775: E/AndroidRuntime(1672):     ... 11 more
03-03 15:23:34.775: E/AndroidRuntime(1672): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.ib.qezyplay.NavigationDrawerFragment did not create a view.
03-03 15:23:34.775: E/AndroidRuntime(1672):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2189)
03-03 15:23:34.775: E/AndroidRuntime(1672):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:297)
03-03 15:23:34.775: E/AndroidRuntime(1672):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreateView(ActionBarActivity.java:547)
03-03 15:23:34.775: E/AndroidRuntime(1672):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
```

**NavigationDrawerFragmen**

```
package com.ib.qezyplay;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView.FindListener;



/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends  Fragment {

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    public static final String PREF_FILE_NAME="testpref";
    public static final String KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER="user_learned_drawer";
    private View containerView;

    public NavigationDrawerFragment()   
    {

    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mUserLearnedDrawer = Boolean.valueOf(readFromPreferences(getActivity(), KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, "false")); 
    }

    public View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer,container,false);
    }


    public void setup(int Fragmentid, DrawerLayout drawerLayout ,Toolbar toolBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        containerView=getActivity().findViewById(Fragmentid);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
        mDrawerToggle = new  ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerLayout, 
                toolBar, R.string.open, R.string.close  ) {

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);

                if(!mUserLearnedDrawer)
                {
                    mUserLearnedDrawer=true;
                    saveToPreferences(getActivity(), KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, mUserLearnedDrawer+"");
                }
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                // Code here will execute once drawer is closed
            }

        };

        if(!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState)
        {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Fragmentid);
        }
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle); 
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });  
    }


    public static  void saveToPreferences(Context context,String preferenceName ,String preferenceValue)
    {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME,context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(preferenceName, preferenceValue);
        editor.apply();

    }

    public static String readFromPreferences(Context context,String preferenceName ,String defaultValue)
    {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME,context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        return sharedPreferences.getString(preferenceName, defaultValue);


    }

}
```

**user_main_screen.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"       
    android:id="@+id/DrawerLayout"    
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >     

<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"    
    android:orientation="vertical" >  

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar  
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"    
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:background="#0000ff" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

   <!--  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" >

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
  -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/previewScreenImageView"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="190dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/videoSurfaceContainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="205dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="260dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="270dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="269dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="270dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" >

        <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/surface_main"
            android:layout_width="484dp"
            android:layout_height="235dp" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <com.ib.coverflow.CoverFlow
        xmlns:coverflow="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.ib.qezyplay"
        android:id="@+id/coverflow"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/preview"
        android:paddingTop="290dp" >
    </com.ib.coverflow.CoverFlow> 

</RelativeLayout>

     <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.ib.qezyplay.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="268dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**fragment_navigation_drawer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff" 
    tools:context="com.ib.qezyplay.NavigationDrawerFragment" >

   <!--  <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rowIcon"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/rowText" /> -->

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: not sure (didn't read it completly) but if you just remove the comments, everything works fine?

Comment: Highlight the Line no. 220 in UserMainScreen.java

Comment: What comments are you talking about ?Are these the one /**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */    removing them is not working

Comment: Line 220 in UsermainScreen.java 
  
  setContentView(R.layout.user_main_screen);

Comment: @ludo he is talking to remove the comments of  `user_main_screen.xml`

Comment: I am still getting error after uncommenting the code in user_main_screen.xml.......I am soo stuck up with this ..Please help guys

Comment: THANKS A LOT.........Thankuuuuuuuuuuuuuu soo much  guys for ur help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is complaining about the fact the DrawerFragment didn't create a view, and for a fragment it means, the onCreateView was not invoked. In your DrawerFragment you have

```
 public View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

which is incorrect. If you just add add the override annotation you will see a compile time error informing you that this method cannot be overridden because it does not exist in the super class. The correct signature is

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

Comment: whenever i include the annotation @Override..Eclipse shows an error on"oncreateView "   and quickfix asks me to remove the  Override annotation

Comment: it says so, because the method's signature is incorrect.

Comment: @ludo: you can thank Blackbelt by marking his answer correct :)